# How to return a datatable from a database table, not using adapter.fill

Tags: c#, ado.net

I wish to return a Datatable not using the adapter.fill technique.

```
    internal DataTable ConnectedSelect(string TableName, string[] Cols, string Condition)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(GenerateSelectStatment(TableName, Cols, Condition),con))
            {
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                object[] temp = new object[rdr.FieldCount];
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                   rdr.GetValues(temp);
                   dt.Rows.Add(temp);
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
    }
```

problem is i get Input array is longer than number of col in this table.
table has 4 columns 
What could be the problem?
the rows.add should be adding a row with 4 elements which is the same as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `load` method of `DataTable`

```
 dt.Load(rdr);
```

Whole code would be

```
internal DataTable ConnectedSelect(string TableName, string[] Cols, string Condition)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(GenerateSelectStatment(TableName, Cols, Condition),con))
        {
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if(rdr.HasRows)
               dt.Load(rdr);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
}
```

Comment: sweet works well :)
but how come there isn't a loop in your code?

Comment: dt.Load(rdr) insert all values of reader in DataTable. loop is not necessary in that case.

Comment: But doesn't the Reader return just one row at a time?
Or does the dt.load force it to return all rows?

Comment: No, The Read() method of DataReader returns one row while DataTable.Load Grabs all the rows of DataReader.